# On a decreasing sequence of compact subsets of a Hausdorff topological space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have the following exercise to solve:

> **Exercise.** Let $ (E,\tau) $ be a Hausdorff topological space and
>     $ (K_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ a decreasing sequence of non-empty
>     $ \tau $-compact subsets of $ E $. Prove that
>     $ \displaystyle K \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_{n} $ is
>     $ \tau $-compact.
>
> Suppose that there exists a $ \tau $-open subset $ U $ of $ E $ such that
>     $ K \subset U $. Then prove that there exists an $ n_{0} \in \mathbb{N} $ such
>     that $ K_{n} \subseteq U $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq n_{0}} $.

---

To prove that $ K $ is $ \tau $-compact, I mentioned that as the $ K_{n} $’s are $ \tau $-compact, they are $ \tau $-closed, so $ K $ is a $ \tau $-closed subset of $ E $ contained within a $ \tau $-compact subset of $ E $. Therefore, $ K $ is $ \tau $-compact.

---

However, I don’t know how to solve the second question or how to see that $ K \neq \varnothing $. Could someone please suggest another method to prove that $ K $ is $ \tau $-compact?

Thank you!

Comment: Is "separated" another word for Hausdorff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post was re-written because the OP apparently had trouble understanding the original version. The argument should be **crystal clear** now.

---

**Proof that $ K $ is a compact subset of $ E $.**

$ K $ is an intersection of closed subsets of $ E $ (in a Hausdorff space, compact subsets are closed), so $ K $ itself is a closed subset by the axioms of a topology. Then as $ K \subseteq K_{1} $ and $ K_{1} $ is a compact subset, it follows that $ K $ is a compact subset as well (a closed subset of a compact subset is compact). $ \quad \clubsuit $

---

**Lemma.** $ K $ is non-empty.

*Proof*

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $ \displaystyle K = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} K_{n} = \varnothing $. Then by de Morgan’s Laws, we have
\begin{align}
    K_{1}
& = K_{1} \setminus \varnothing \\
& = K_{1} \bigg\backslash \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} K_{n} \\
& = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} (K_{1} \setminus K_{n}).
\end{align}
Let $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. Observe that $ K_{1} \setminus K_{n} = K_{1} \cap (E \setminus K_{n}) $, which shows that $ K_{1} \setminus K_{n} $ is the intersection of $ K_{1} $ with an open subset of $ E $. By definition, $ K_{1} \setminus K_{n} $ is thus a $ K_{1} $-open subset of $ K_{1} $.

Hence, $ \mathcal{O} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \{ K_{1} \setminus K_{n} \}_{n = 1}^{\infty} $ is a $ K_{1} $-open cover of $ K_{1} $, and as $ K_{1} $ is a compact topological space, we can find natural numbers $ n_{1},\ldots,n_{k} $ such that $ \mathcal{O}' \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \{ K_{1} \setminus K_{n_{i}} \}_{i = 1}^{k} $ is a finite $ K_{1} $-open subcover of $ K_{1} $. Without any loss of generality, we may assume that $ n_{1} < \ldots < n_{k} $, which yields
\begin{align}
             K_{1}
& =          \bigcup_{i = 1}^{k} (K_{1} \setminus K_{n_{i}}) \\
& =          K_{1} \bigg\backslash \bigcap_{i = 1}^{k} K_{n_{i}} \qquad
             (\text{By de Morgan’s Laws again.}) \\
& =          K_{1} \setminus K_{n_{k}} \qquad
             (\text{As $ K_{n_{k}} \subseteq \ldots \subseteq K_{n_{1}} $.}) \\
& \subsetneq K_{1}. \qquad
(\text{As $ K_{n_{k}} \subseteq K_{1} $ and $ K_{n_{k}} \neq \varnothing $ by hypothesis.})
\end{align}
We thus have the contradiction $ K_{1} \subsetneq K_{1} $, and so our assumption that $ K $ is empty is truly rubbish. Therefore, $ K $ is *non-empty*. $ \quad \spadesuit $

---

**Theorem.** If $ K \subseteq U $ for some open subset $ U $ of $ E $, then there exists an $ n_{0} \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ K_{n} \subseteq U $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq n_{0}} $.

*Proof*

Suppose that $ K \subseteq U $ for some open subset $ U $ of $ E $. Then
\begin{align}
    \varnothing
& = K \setminus U \\
& = \left( \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} K_{n} \right) \bigg\backslash U \\
& = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} (K_{n} \setminus U).
\end{align}
Let $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. Observe that $ K_{n} \setminus U = K_{n} \cap (E \setminus U) $, which implies that $ K_{n} $ is an intersection of two closed subsets of $ E $. Hence, $ K_{n} \setminus U $ is a closed subset, and as it is at the same time contained inside the compact subset $ K_{n} $, it is a compact subset as well.

We now see that $ (K_{n} \setminus U)_{n = 1}^{\infty} $ is a *decreasing* sequence of compact subsets of $ E $ whose intersection is empty. The lemma above tells us that if all members of this sequence were non-empty, then their intersection would be non-empty as well. However, this is not the case! Hence, some member of the sequence must be empty, i.e., $ K_{n_{0}} \setminus U = \varnothing $ for some $ n_{0} \in \mathbb{N} $, or equivalently, $ K_{n_{0}} \subseteq U $. Then as
$$
          \ldots
\subseteq K_{n_{0} + 3}
\subseteq K_{n_{0} + 2}
\subseteq K_{n_{0} + 1}
\subseteq K_{n_{0}}
\subseteq U,
$$
we conclude that $ K_{n} \subseteq U $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq n_{0}} $. $ \quad \blacksquare $

Comment: i know this i need an other method and a hint or a solution for the seconde question and why $K\neq\emptyset$

Comment: I see. I had a hard time separating what was being asked from what were your attempts at the problem.

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I have added more details concerning the second question.

Comment: I don't understand why 
$\bigcap_{i = 1}^{k} K_{n_{i}}
=  K_{n_{k}}$ we have that $n_1<n_k$ so $K_{n_k}\subset K_{n_1}$ and if $K_{n_k}=K_1$ we proved nothing...

Comment: I forgot to add the condition that $ n_{1} < n_{2} < \ldots < n_{k} $, which can easily be arranged. You will then obtain
$$
\bigcap_{i = 1}^{k} K_{n_{i}} = K_{n_{k}}.
$$
If $ K_{n_{k}} = K_{1} $, then it does not damage my argument because I am aiming for a contradiction with $ K_{1} $, which is non-empty, on the extreme left and something strictly smaller than $ K_{1} $ on the extreme right. If $ K_{n_{k}} = K_{1} $, then even better because I now get $ K_{1} = \varnothing $, which is still a contradiction.

Comment: The contradiction is with the $K_1=K_1\setminus K_{n_k}\subset K_1$ and $K_1\neq \emptyset$ right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21359/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-berrick-fillmore).

Comment: if there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K_{n_0}\subset U$ why $\forall n\geq n_0, K_{n}\subset U$ ? please

Comment: @Vrouvrou Think about it.  The $K_{n}$'s are nested, which means $K_{1} \supseteq K_{2} \supseteq K_{3} \supseteq ...$.  Now, if $U \supseteq K_{n_{0}}$, then since for all $n \geq n_{0}$, $K_{n_{0}} \supseteq K_{n}$, it follows that if $U \supseteq K_{n_{0}}$, $U \supseteq K_{n}$ for all $n \geq n_{0}$.

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes, you’re right. We have $ K_{1} \neq \varnothing $ on the extreme left, and we have $ K_{1} \setminus K_{n_{k}} $, which is *strictly smaller than* $ K_{1} $, on the extreme right. Why $ K_{1} \setminus K_{n_{k}} $ should be strictly smaller than $ K_{1} $ is because $ K_{n_{k}} $ is a non-empty subset of $ K_{1} $, by your assumption that $ (K_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is a decreasing sequence of non-empty sets. The contradiction we have here is therefore that of a set being equal to a strict subset of itself.

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Regarding your second point, simply observe that
$$
          \ldots
\subseteq K_{n_{0} + 2}
\subseteq K_{n_{0} + 1}
\subseteq K_{n_{0}}
\subseteq U.
$$
When we have $ A \subseteq B \subseteq C $, shouldn’t $ A \subseteq C $? This is basic set theory. :)

Comment: why $K_1\setminus K_n$ is open ?

Comment: @BerrickFillmore $K_1\setminus K_n$ is open in $K_1$ or in $E$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: $ K_{1} \setminus K_{n} $ is $ K_{1} $-open (i.e., open in $ K_{1} $ with respect to the subspace topology on $ K_{1} $ inherited from $ E $), not $ E $-open. Observe that
$$
  K_{1} \setminus K_{n}
= K_{1} \cap
  \underbrace{(E \setminus K_{n})}_{\text{$ E $-open subset}},
$$
so $ K_{1} \setminus K_{n} $ is $ K_{1} $-open. However, $ K_{1} $, being a compact subset of $ E $, is a compact topological space in its own right, so as $ (K_{1} \setminus K_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is a $ K_{1} $-open cover of $ K_{1} $, we can extract a finite $ K_{1} $-open sub-cover.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore thank you

Comment: @BerrickFillmore for the question "Suppose that there exist an open set $U\subset E$ such that $K\subset U$. prove that there exist $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq n_0, K_n\subset U$ " i found a proof in a book it says: By contradiction suppose that for all $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $n\geq n_0$ and $K_n\not\subset U$ then for all $n\in \N$ there exists an element$x_n\in K_n$ and $x_n\in C_E U$ closed

Comment: because $(K_n)$ is decreasing then $(x_n)\subset K_0$ witch is compact then $(x_n)$ has a limit point in $\overline{\cap K_n}=\cap K_n\subset \Omega$ but $(x_n)$ is in $C_e \Omega$ contradiction .

Comment: i dont understand the relation between the fact that $(x_n)\subset K_0$ and the fact that it's limit point must be in $\overline{\cap K_n}$ ? thank you

Comment: I’m confused because you’re using non-standard terminology and I don’t know what $ \Omega $ is, but here’s what I think about this other argument.

Let $ x $ be a limit point of $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $. By definition, $ x $ is the limit of a subsequence $ (x_{n_{k}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} $ of $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $. Now, for each $ N \in \mathbb{N} $, as all members of this subsequence, **after some sufficiently large index**, must lie in $ K_{N} $, we see that $ x $ is the limit of some subsequence of $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ whose members all lie in $ K_{N} $.

Comment: Then as $ K_{N} $ is a closed subset of $ E $, we automatically have $ x \in K_{N} $. However, this is true for all $ N \in \mathbb{N} $, so $ \displaystyle x \in \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} K_{n} = K \subseteq U $.

On the other hand, $ x_{n} \in K_{0} \setminus U $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, and as $ K_{0} \setminus U $ is also a closed subset of $ E $, we must have $ x \in K_{0} \setminus U $. Therefore, we obtain $ x \in U $ **and** $ x \notin U $, which is a contradiction.